# How to develop intuition about parameter estimation in AR-GARCH model?

Tags: regression, estimation, garch

consider a typical ar-garch model:

$y = \sum{b_ix_i} + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim \text{garch}(p,q)$

In such case a typical textbook says that we should first estimate all bi's and then estimate the garch parameters, because regression parameters and garch parameters are independent to each other (asymptotically.)

Although it should be right, I do not understand the logic behind that. In general, if 2 sets of estimates (of model parameters) are independent, then can we estimate first set first then the second set?

Can somebody please teach me the intuition over that?

Comment: Which typical textbook says that? The textbooks I use for teaching GARCH processes tells that all the parameters are easily estimated using maximum likelihood, in fact it is trivial to modify the likelihood function to accomodate AR part.

Comment: I was following this book: New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis
By Lütkepohl, Helmut

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

Which typical textbook says that? The textbooks I use for teaching GARCH processes tells that all the parameters are easily estimated using maximum likelihood, in fact it is trivial to modify the likelihood function to accomodate AR part. – mpiktas

( I was following this book: New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis By Lütkepohl, Helmut – Bogaso )